# Understanding difference in inference through SubClassOf and EquivalentTo in Protege with HermiT

Tags: owl, protege, inference

I would be grateful if someone could explain the following behaviour to me.

Assume the following classes/subclasses:

```
Meal
  |----SmallMeal
  |----BigMeal
```

Where

```
Meal hasSize exactly 1 xsd:decimal
```

Further given a set of individuals of *Meal* with specified size.
I want to infer the subtype of meal for the given individuals.

So my first idea would be additional *SubClass Of*-relationships like:

```
BigMeal 'SubClass Of' hasSize exactly 1 xsd:decimal[>= 2.5]
```

Which would not type the individuals at all.
But switching *SubClass Of* with *Equivalent To* will yield the correct
categorization. I don't understand why.
It seems a little bit odd to declare equivalence, for there could exist many things with a decimal size value that are not meals of type *SmallMeal* or *BigMeal*.

Comment: So make it *EquivalentTo:* `Meal that hasSize exactly 1 xsd:decimal[>= 2.5]`.

Comment: Jeah, that works. But I want to understand, why the second works while the first doesn't.

Comment: Well, try to add to your initial ontology `Meal` *EquivalentTo* `BigMeal or SmallMeal`.